Can't multi-target projects in azure pipeline build
I have a project which is targeting both net472 and netstandard2.0 and this has conditional package references and conditional code.
If I compile this locally completes with no errors and also if I compile the solution via msbuild.
However when I compile with msbuild task in azure build pipeline it throw errors like:

##[error]tests\Project.Tests\RiskUi\RiskUiProviderTests.cs(21,17): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RiskUiProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
My problem is like this link: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/4435
The class RiskUiProvider is under a directive #if NET472  public class RiskUiProvider {} #endif it belongs to a project that is multitargeting <TargetFrameworks>net472;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
and the unit test which is net472 is throwing this error as if he doesn't read under the directive.

Has anyone else had/solved this same issue?
I added the reference of the multitargeting project like this:
<ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Standard\Project.Standard.csproj">
    <AdditionalProperties>TargetFramework=net472</AdditionalProperties>
    <Name>Project.Standard</Name>
</ProjectReference>

but it is like in azure pipeline he can"t read directives (#if NET472) and the strange that in local it all works and it is running
yaml file
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution All.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: All.sln
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /p:AutoGenerateBindingRedirects=true /p:GeneratePackageOnBuild=True /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=True /p:PackageOutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\NuGet /p:IncludeSymbols=true /p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg /target:Build '
    clean: true

- task: VSTest@3
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\Project.UnitTests\Project.UnitTests.dll
    
    searchFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\TU'
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=UnitTest & TestCategory!=Slow & TestCategory!=PerfNonRegTest'
    runInParallel: false
    codeCoverageEnabled: false
    otherConsoleOptions: '/Platform:$(BuildPlatform) /Framework:.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['DisableUnitTests'], 'false'))
  timeoutInMinutes: 30```

The csproj of test
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">   <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{48F901E6-F500-477A-B03C-4B6B2E8E362C}</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <SccProjectName></SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath></SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath></SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider></SccProvider>
    <AssemblyTitle>LtCore.Tests</AssemblyTitle>
    <Product>LtCore.Tests</Product>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
    <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType> </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>   </PropertyGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NFluent" Version="2.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.5" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
  
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Project.Standard\Project.Standard.csproj">
      <AdditionalProperties>TargetFramework=net472</AdditionalProperties>
    </ProjectReference>   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>

    <Content Include="log4net.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>   </ItemGroup> </Project>



Testing from my side, the pipeline works as expected. Share the projects and yaml file for your reference.

My MultiTargetingLibrary.csproj

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472'">
    <DefineConstants>NET472</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>


RiskUiProvider.cs in project MultiTargetingLibrary

#if NET472
public class RiskUiProvider
{
    ...
}
#endif



My MultiTargetingLibrary.Tests.csproj

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.5.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.5.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MultiTargetingLibrary\MultiTargetingLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="Xunit" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


My YAML file of the build pipeline

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.x' # Adjust based on your .NET SDK version

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


Update:
Root cause:
When you use /p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in msbuildArguments, the subfolder obj\Release\netstandard2.0 and obj\Release\net472 will not be created in the artifact directory, so that the dll for net472 is override by netstandard2.0.
Solution:
Add the following to test project.
<ProjectName>$(AssemblyName).$(TargetFramework)</ProjectName> 
<PackageOutputPath>$(OutDir)</PackageOutputPath>


I added the yaml in my description the confusing thing is that unit test takes the dll of Project.Standard in netstandard2.0 instead of net472 that's why he doesn't execute the code under the directive  #if NET472

In my pipeline, the test takes dll of the project in net472. What's the ,csproj of your test project?

I added the csproj in the description

I found that the problem when running the msbuild taks he make CopyFilesToOutputDirectory twice so that the dll of netstandard replace the dll of net472 "E:\agent_work\55\s\src\LTCore.Standard\obj\Release\netstandard2.0\LTCore.Standard.dll" to "E:\agent_work\55\a\LTCore.Standard\LTCore.Standard.dll". and other one  Copying file from "E:\agent_work\55\s\src\LTCore.Standard\obj\Release\net472\LTCore.Standard.dll" to "E:\agent_work\55\a\LTCore.Standard\LTCore.Standard.dll"

I can reproduce the same error. The reason of the issue is that when you use /p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in msbuildArguments, the subfolder obj\Release\netstandard2.0 and obj\Release\net472 will not be created in the artifact directory, so that the dll for net472 is overrided by netstandard2.0. To resolve this issue, remove /p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in MSBuild@1 task and change searchFolder of VSTest@2 task from $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\TU to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory). Then the build will work as expected.

If you need to put the dll to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory), you can do it after VSTest task by using a copy file task.

The solution was to add $(AssemblyName).$(TargetFramework)
$(OutDir)

@rahma sayadi, thanks for your update. To help others who may have the same issue, I update the answer above with the root cause and solution.
